# SWIFT: MediaPlayer - Done Button doesn't do anything

Tags: ios, swift, video, media-player, mplayer

so I have the following code working great! for anyone wanting to get a video working in SWIFT. The issue is, after the video finishes it remains on the video. Even when pressing **Done** nothing happens...

**How can I close the video back to one of the existing View Controllers?**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playVideo()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func playVideo() {

    //Get the Video Path
    //You need to put this in Project->Target->copy bundle resource for this to work
    let videoPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Quizzes", ofType:"mov")

    //Make a URL from your path
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(videoPath!)

    //Initalize the movie player
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

    if let player = moviePlayer {

        //Make the player scale the entire view
        player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        player.scalingMode = .AspectFill

        //Add it as a subView to your currentView
        self.view.addSubview(player.view)

        //Play the video
        player.prepareToPlay()

    }
    else {
        print("Movie player couldn't be initialized")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added it as subview

> self.view.addSubview(player.view)

You also need to remove it where is that code?
Please use removeFromSuperview when done playing.